# Clarification needed for CSS selector

Tags: css

Can someone please explain the below CSS code:

```
html:not([dir="rtl"]){
    //some CSS property
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html:not([dir="rtl"])
```

Let's break it down!

---

```css
html
```

Selects all `html` elements (there's *most likely* only one)...

```css
:not( ... )
```

... that do [*not*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)...

```css
[dir="rtl"]
```

... have the [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `dir` set to `"rtl"`.

So, to sum it up, it selects all `html` elements that do *not* have `dir` set to `"rtl"`. Example:

```html
<html>  <!-- Would match! -->

<html lang="en">  <!-- Would match! -->

<html dir>  <!-- Would match! -->

<html dir="ltr">  <!-- Would match! -->

<html dir="rtl">  <!-- Would NOT match! -->
```

Comment: It has only to do with html tag.  Other tags won't be affected. Correct?

Comment: Correct! If you did `*:not([dir="rtl"])` it would match _any tag_ that had `dir="rtl"` ([because * is the universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors))

Comment: it would match any tag that did / 'did not' have  `dir="rtl"`  ??

Comment: Oh, my bad! That _did not have_ `dir="rtl"`

Answer (score 1):

It will select all `html` tags that don't have the attribute `dir` with value `rtl`.

### Each part:

Select html tag: `html`

Select the inverse: `:not()`

Select an attribute with specific value: `[attribute="value"]`

Comment: By everything, you mean only html tags. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is `:not()` pseudo-class and inside is attribute selector, so it will select `html` if it doesn't have `dir="rtl"` attribute which is text-direction set right to left.